# ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

Good Evening,

I am experiencing a strange problem. I only experience the problem when the site has been deployed to IIS 7.0. The web page renders fine when launched in VS 2010; however when viewed to IIS 7.0 the entire page gets shifted to the right.

```
errors only happen when this is on the .aspx page
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager" runat="server" />
```

Web.config file below....

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks,
Brennan

---

Web.config ---

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="WebLinkMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="WebLinkMembershipProvider" type="WebLinkUI.Providers.WebLinkMembershipProvider" applicationName="/WebLink" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
  </controls>
</pages>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: I can email them...Sorry, I cannot upload them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using IIS7  Integrated Mode, the following entry was required by IIS 7 in the  section instead of

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode"  
verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd"  
type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Thanks,
Brennan

Comment: this should be entered in web.server/handlers

Comment: For me it had nothing to do with Telerik but still worked.  Mine happened after I integrated ASP.Net Membership but more specifically once I added the <authorization> portion of the web.config file.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case this helps somebody else:

I had the same problem - my website work was working in .NET 3.5, but when I updated to .NET 4.0 a Telerik RadTabStrip stopped working.

The problem was the handler entry. This was in the *handlers* section (under *<system.webserver>*) in my web.config file:

---

<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd"
                  type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*"
                 preCondition="integratedMode,**runtimeVersionv2.0**"/>

---

I removed the runtimeVersion2.0 precondition, and it worked.

It's only obvious once you've spotted it :-)

Comment: Had tried..
Running aspnet_regiis -i on the folder of the Framework 4.0.
Repairing of 'MS .NET Framework 4 Client Profile' and 'MS .NET Framework 4 Extended'.
Installing VS 2010 SP1 following other links..but finally this change solved it. thanks

Comment: Dude.  I literally spent 4 hrs trying to figure this out.  I wish I could buy you a drink, or at least up vote this a couple hundred times.

Comment: This was more useful than the Telerik help site!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If a site works on the ASP.NET Development server and fails on IIS 7+, then the problem might be related to the handlers/modules configuration - IIS 7 in integrated mode looks for handlers in the <**system.webServer**> while ASP.NET Dev server and IIS 6 look in the <**system.web**> section. In this case you should make sure that all handlers and modules are correctly registered in both sections, or switch your IIS application pool to classic mode instead of integrated mode.