# how can i get Response of OK button message box in client page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can i get Response of OK button message box in client page.

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" Your time has been finished "');", true);

this code is working in simple way means without getting any response.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly start your further activity in next line . on click of OK button it will return to your next line .

//your code goes here...
//for example:-

```
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" Your time has been finished "');", true);
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbs = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sbs.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    sbs.Append("window.location = 'http://www.google.com/'");//or whatever you want:-
    sbs.Append("</script>");
    Type tr = this.GetType();
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(tr, "PopupScript2", sbs.ToString());
```

Comment: But i want redirect the page after pressing ok button is it possible in javascript 
sbs.Append("Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")");
its not working..
Now what to do..

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" Your time has been finished "');", true);
System.Text.StringBuilder sds = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sds.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
sds.Append("window.location='http://localhost:49882/cybus/Home.aspx/'");
sds.Append("/script");
Type tr = this.GetType();        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(tr,"PopupScript2",sds.ToString());

I added this code but i got java script runtime error that is :-Microsoft JScript runtime error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Comment: this piece of code is working fine for me . or else you can check this link for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695351/ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-asp-net-4-0