# NoBotState is always InvalidBadResponse (AjaxContorlToolKit)

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastNm" runat="server" CssClass="ETextField1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSend" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Send" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="Transparent" ImageUrl="~/images/Buttons/submit.png"  Height="34" Width="100" onclick="btnSend_Click" />

<cc1:NoBot ID="NoBot1" runat="server" OnGenerateChallengeAndResponse="NoBot1_GenerateChallengeAndResponse" ResponseMinimumDelaySeconds="3"
                      CutoffMaximumInstances="5" CutoffWindowSeconds="60" />
```

It works locally. But when I upload it on server it shows every time `InvalidBadResponse`

I enter data for login and click on asp button. NoBot state is InvalidBadResponse and it fails. But, then I click on browser's refresh button it asks me to resend request I say ok and now state is valid! Why?

Same thing same problem like : [AjaxControlToolkit NoBotState is always InvalidBadResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915240/ajaxcontroltoolkit-nobotstate-is-always-invalidbadresponse)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here: [AjaxControlToolkit NoBotState is always InvalidBadResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915240/ajaxcontroltoolkit-nobotstate-is-always-invalidbadresponse/16379127#16379127)

Basically, my url re-writing was messing up the ASP.NET ajax framework libraries' urls, causing them not to load - meaning the Javascript challenge would always fail because it wasn't being executed.