# ScriptResource not loading

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ektron

This is an interesting problem...

I've got an ASP.NET 3.5 web application. It's relatively simple - a content page based on a master page, with a couple of usercontrols on the page.

There are a total of four controls on the page; two are custom controls and two are Ektron CMS controls.

For some reason, I've been getting 'Sys is undefined' Javascript errors. The Firebug error console also throws an "ASP.NET client framework failed to load" error. I can't figure out *why* this is happening.

The kicker - if I take the controls that don't work completely out of the content page, they work just fine. It's obviously something in the content page trashing the framework, but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

I've looked through several dozen articles before posting, including suggestions like:

- Repairing the .NET framework (didn't work)
- Various web.config tweaks (either already there or didn't work)
- regiis -i command (I don't think this will help, since the controls **do** work when I'm not using the content page)
- Commenting out custom scripts on the user controls (didn't work)
- Commenting out the other user controls on the page (didn't work)
- Create a blank page and drop **only** the control I'm interested in on the page (this actually works)

Has anyone seen something like this before? It's **got** to be something in that content page, but I'm struggling with what.

**EDIT**

I noticed while stepping through the code the UserControl's PAGE_LOAD event fires three times; on the third time the code throws an error. (I'm still trying to get my head around the error that's being thrown)

**EDIT**

I wanted to add this in case someone else sees this error. It turns out the problem was being caused by a Scriptmanager on the page template that wasn't needed.

When I took the Scriptmanager off the page, everything worked fine and the framework load error went away. I figure this problem must have broken other scripts and prevented them from running later on down the page.

Comment: Have you looked at the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695351/ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load-asp-net-4-0 not certain its a duplicate but the symptoms seem similar

Comment: @kd - I did see that, but that's a 4.0 question and I'm running 3.5

Comment: did you delcare the scriptmanager on the page? can you see the include of scriptresource.axd in the source code?

Comment: @slfan - I can see the scriptresource include, but trying to browse to it throws a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a 404 on ScriptResource.axd, there must be something wrong with your ASP.NET installation. I had this before, when I did not configure the correct ASP.NET pool. For instance: there could be another ASP.NET application on the same server assigned to the same pool, that is running under ASP.NET 2.0. You say your application runs under 3.5. Can you try iisreset on your machine and then start your application?

The pool could be assinged to the wrong .NET version.
Another option could be, that .NET 3.5 is not installed on the server at all.

Are you sure that the site runs well without your content page? ScriptResource.axd is a dynamic handler to generate JavaScript on the fly. If it's not available, the scripts cannot work.

Comment: I've tried resetting IIS (using IISReset) and the application comes back up. When I move the control in question to a blank content page, it works fine. I just found an error in one of the other controls that was on the page - it's no longer throwing the exception, but the control still isn't working.  I've also confirmed the IIS settings/application pools seem to be OK.

Comment: As long as the ScriptManager throws a 404, the JavaScript will never work. I think you have to investigate in this direction. Is the .axd extension mapped correctly? (e.g. does trace.axd work?)

Comment: I finally got this to work - the problem was a ScriptManager in the page that obviously wasn't needed...when I removed the offending ScriptManager, the page worked! (Darned if I can figure out why the pathing on this particular page is failing)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of Sys needs to be AFTER your ScriptManager is setup on the page.  The ScriptManager is what instantiates the Sys object.

Comment: Hi Matt, there's a scriptmanager on the page defined before the functions that are supposed to be calling it...

Comment: Do you know what control is referencing Sys?  Is it your custom control or something from your CMS?